# Extract Image URLs from html text using Postgres sql Query

Tags: postgresql, query, array

I have a column in postgres db in which html contain stored. Like this

```
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong><img alt="" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579121477063-4026649ad6d3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" style="float: right; width: 450px; height: 450px;" />&iquest;C&Oacute;MO HACER HUEVO DURO?</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Los huevos duros se han transformado en un cl&aacute;sico de la alimentaci&oacute;n de los chilenos, ya sea para llevarlos a diferentes actividades o simplemente como la prote&iacute;na que se necesita en una comida diaria. Pero, a pesar de tener una preparaci&oacute;n simple, no siempre se logra obtener el resultado que se desea.</p>
<p><strong>ERRORES EN LA COCCI&Oacute;N</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Uno de los errores cl&aacute;sicos al hacer un huevo duro, es el tiempo de cocci&oacute;n. Esto puede causar que la yema quede muy cocida o que esta quede cruda junto a la clara y al intentar retirar la c&aacute;scara, se nos rompa el huevo.</p>
<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: justify;">Para que esta quede centrada y no cargado hacia ning&uacute;n extremo, debes estar constantemente dando vueltas el huevo durante los primeros 4 minutos de la cocci&oacute;n, as&iacute; la yema ir&aacute; rotando dentro de la clara durante los minutos en donde comienza su solidificaci&oacute;n.</p>
<p dir="ltr"><strong>4- Sobrecocci&oacute;n</strong></p>
<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: justify;">Una vez transcurrido el tiempo estimado en el agua hirviendo, retirar con precauci&oacute;n el huevo de la olla y ponerlo bajo agua fr&iacute;a para detener que el calor interno siga cociendo la yema.</p>
<p><img alt="" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550623627-2b70a7772e7a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" style="float: left; width: 450px; height: 450px;" /><img alt="" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1426023671131-18ce9c8d5f80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=753&q=80" style="float: right; width: 450px; height: 450px;" /></p>
<p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>
<p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>
```

Now I want to fetch all image urls also first image url from this text.
All image URLs:

```
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579121477063-4026649ad6d3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550623627-2b70a7772e7a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1426023671131-18ce9c8d5f80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=753&q=80
```

And first image URL from above URLs

```
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579121477063-4026649ad6d3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80
```

How to write query for this result?
Thanks!

Comment: Formulate the criteria which allows to say "This fragment of text is image URL".

Comment: Maybe using Perl? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150399/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No. any other way?